# Using jQuery selectors with Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an Ajax call and response (see the code below.) Prior to this, I had regular javascript code that would successfully turn my `select` element from a traditional select to a select2 widget.

When I try to change the select into the select2 with the javascript code `$('#datepicker').datepicker();` in the response from Ajax call, I get an error in the debugger that says

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (createschedule.php:46)`

Here is the code that is inside the javascript function:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
                {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                    {
                        document.getElementById("row_"+cur_id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        $('#teacherselect').select2({ width: '100%' }); 
                        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "editrow.php?id="+id, true);
                xhttp.send();
```

When Ajax returns and this code is executed, does it still have access to the items through jQuery? It appears that it does not.

Comment: When is this kicked off?  Is the page fully loaded?

Comment: if you comment out that line, do you get an error on the datapicker line?

Comment: This is kicked off when a user presses a button (an image). @Bindrid

Comment: When I comment that out, the datepicker works successfully... that is really weird now.

Comment: so it sounds to me like your select 2 include is not loading, can you verify its path?

Comment: Okay, something happened, because now the old version is having the same problem, meaning you are probably right with the path or something. I had it working a different way and now going back to that, I am seeing the same problem, so I will go get it back working the non ajax way, and that should clear up the ajax way. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Ah, thank you. If you want to add the answer, I'll accept it. Long story short, when I added the includes for the datepicker, it messed up the includes for the select2, probably because they were different jquery versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your jQuery and JQuery UI are working correctly, I would start checking the path of the select2. Is it local or a CDN?

Comment: Thank you. I had two conflicting versions of jquery loading... one for the select2 and the other for the datepicker (jQuery UI)